# How to print the contents of a text file with proper formatting using php

Tags: php

I am trying to print the contents of file say atextfile.txt using php but the formatting of the file is getting all messed up. Say my text file contains following content:

```
    firstline
    secondline
```

Now when I use:

```
    echo file_get_contents("atextfile.txt");
```

It shows everything without formatting like this:

```
    firstline secondline
```

How do i show the content of file with proper formatting or if possible open the file in the text editor like notepad++ or sublime directly through the php script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're outputting it in an HTML document, use `<pre>` to indicate that it has formatting that shouldn't be removed.

```
echo '<pre>' . file_get_contents("atextfile.txt") . '</pre>';
```

Comment: Awesome.. It worked thanks a bunch it really helped me out.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple free online editors which you could incorporate in your page.  Recommending one would be off-topic.

Note that your main problem comes from the fact that new lines have no visual impact in HTML.  You can use [`nl2br()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php) to convert the new lines to HTML `<br/>` tags.